# Error while submitting a form built with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to create a form based on a received object: At this stage I have 2 input type text, 1 input date, 1 select.

```
[
    {"name" : "name", "fieldType": "input", "type": "text", "values": []},
    {"name" : "surname", "fieldType": "input", "type": "text", "values": []},
    {"name" : "address", "fieldType": "input", "type": "text", "values": []},
    {"name" : "birthdate", "fieldType": "input", "type": "date", "values": []},
    {"name" : "sex", "fieldType": "select", "type": null, "values": 
        [{"key": "1", "value": "Male"}, {"key": "2", "value": "Female"}]
    },
]
```

Now to create the form i created a method :

```
const buildForm = () => {
    let requestForm = document.createElement('form');
    requestForm.setAttribute("id", "requestForm");

    let parentFormDiv = document.getElementById("displayForm");
    parentFormDiv.appendChild(requestForm);

    let formRow = document.createElement('div');
    formRow.setAttribute("class", "row");

    let butRow = document.createElement('div');
    butRow.setAttribute("class", "row");

    let formElt = document.getElementById('requestForm');
    formElt.appendChild(formRow);
    formElt.appendChild(butRow);

    formInputs.forEach(element => {
        // for inputs : works for date & text
        if(element.fieldType === "input") {
            formRow.innerHTML += `
                <label for="${element.name}">${element.name}</label>
                <input id="${element.name}" name="${element.name}" type="${element.type}" >
            `;
        }
        // for selects
        if(element.fieldType === "select") {
            formRow.innerHTML += `
                <label for="${element.name}">${element.name}</label>
                <select id="${element.name}" name="${element.name}"></select>
            `;

            let selectId = element.name;
            let selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);

            for (let item of element.values) {
                let option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = item.key;
                option.text = item.value;
                selectList.appendChild(option);
            }
            formRow.innerHTML += `</select>`;
        }
        butRow.innerHTML= `<button id="btnOk" name="btnOk" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>`;
    });
};
```

I call this method onLoad :

```
window.addEventListener("load", buildForm);
```

It builds correctly the form as expected. My issue concerns how i send the form and convert it onto json.

I added another eventListener on the form :

```
const form = document.getElementById('requestForm');
form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit);
```

In order to manage the submit, I added a method :

```
const handleFormSubmit = event => {
    // Stop the form from submitting since we’re handling that with AJAX.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Call our function to get the form data.
    const data = formToJSON(form.elements);
    // Demo only: print the form data onscreen as a formatted JSON object.
    console.log(data);
    const dataContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('results__display')[0];
    dataContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, "  ");

    console.log(data);    
};
```

Which calls this conversion method :

```
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
    // Make sure the element has the required properties and should be added.
    if (isValidElement(element) && isValidValue(element)) {
        // Some fields allow multiple values => require arrays
        if (isCheckbox(element)) {
            data[element.name] = (data[element.name] || []).concat(element.value);
        } else if (isMultiSelect(element)) {
            data[element.name] = getSelectValues(element);
        } else {
            data[element.name] = element.value;
        }
    }
    return data;
}, {});
```

I obtain this error message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. 
This error concerns this specific line :

```
form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit);
```

And i'm not entering in the method while debugging.

I can't remove the create attribute of the form because this code is going to be implemented in a Sharepoint online WebPart component.

Comment: Why don't you `addEventListener` to your form when you build it ? I am guessing your form element is not inserted into your DOM yet when you call `document.getElementById`

Comment: On load I added the event listener that call buildForm. The second event listener should only be triggered on a submit specif to the form that has been generated. If the form is already loaded on the page, i wonder why i can listen to event on it

Comment: At a guess `document.getElementById('requestForm')` doesn't find anything because the form hasn't been added to the DOM (yet).

Comment: Yes ! i just noticed how stupid the solution was while reading your answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to add event listener to the form before the form is created since you're creating the form on load. You could try adding this event listener inside the buildForm method, where you've got a reference to the element already.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the const form into the handleFormSubmit method. It was an issue of scope of the constant. It was setted before it was created i guess..

```
const handleFormSubmit = event => {
    const form = document.getElementById('requestForm');

    // Stop the form from submitting since we’re handling that with AJAX.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Call our function to get the form data.
    const data = formToJSON(form.elements);
    // Demo only: print the form data onscreen as a formatted JSON object.
    console.log(data);
};
```